# Convert numerical month to string using ionic 2 Pipe

Tags: json, ionic2, date-pipe

How can I convert month to string in ionic 2 using Pipe? given the sample data below:

In my .ts file

```
let users = [
 {
   user: "A",
   birthDate: "2017-08-01"
 },
 {
   user: "B",
   birthDate: "2017-08-02"
 },
 {
   user: "C",
   birthDate: "2017-08-03"
 },
 {
   user: "D",
   birthDate: "2017-08-04"
 }
]
```

In my .html file

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
    <div>Name: {{user.name}}</div>
    <div>Birth Date: {{user.birthDate | date: "MM dd, yyyy"}}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The sample output will be

```
Name: A
Birth Date: 08 01, 2017
Name: B
Birth Date: 08 02, 2017
Name: C
Birth Date: 08 03, 2017
Name: D
Birth Date: 08 04, 2017
```

Expected output will be

```
Name: A
Birth Date: August 01, 2017
Name: B
Birth Date: August 02, 2017
Name: C
Birth Date: August 03, 2017
Name: D
Birth Date: August 04, 2017
```

How can I achieve expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MMMM` instead of `MM`

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
    <div>Name: {{user.name}}</div>
    <div>Birth Date: {{user.birthDate | date: "MMMM dd, yyyy"}}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```